# 3 test cases would fail with SbSocketGetInterfaceAddressTest in NPLB

Tags: cobalt

we run the nplb test both on the x86-x11 and arm-linux plarform with cobalt Release 11.104700 version, the `SbSocketGetInterfaceAddressTest` test would both fail, so it seemed to be the issue of NPLB itself, can someone have a look?

```
    [  FAILED  ] SbSocketAddressTypes/SbSocketGetInterfaceAddressTest.SunnyDayDestination/1, where GetParam() = 1
    [  FAILED  ] SbSocketAddressTypes/SbSocketGetInterfaceAddressTest.SunnyDaySourceForDestination/1, where GetParam() = 1
    [  FAILED  ] SbSocketAddressTypes/SbSocketGetInterfaceAddressTest.SunnyDaySourceNotLoopback/1, where GetParam() = 1

1>SbSocketAddressTypes/SbSocketGetInterfaceAddressTest.SunnyDayDestination/1
../../starboard/nplb/socket_get_interface_address_test.cc:85: Failure
Value of: SbSocketGetInterfaceAddress(&destination, &source, NULL)
  Actual: false
Expected: true
../../starboard/nplb/socket_get_interface_address_test.cc:86: Failure
Value of: source.type == GetAddressType()
  Actual: false
Expected: true
../../starboard/nplb/socket_get_interface_address_test.cc:87: Failure
Value of: SbSocketGetInterfaceAddress(&destination, &source, &netmask)
  Actual: false
Expected: true
../../starboard/nplb/socket_get_interface_address_test.cc:93: Failure
Value of: GetAddressType()
  Actual: 1
Expected: source.type
Which is: 4278124286
../../starboard/nplb/socket_get_interface_address_test.cc:94: Failure
Value of: GetAddressType()
  Actual: 1
Expected: netmask.type
Which is: 4278124286
../../starboard/nplb/socket_get_interface_address_test.cc:95: Failure
Value of: 0
Expected: source.port
Which is: -16843010

2>SbSocketAddressTypes/SbSocketGetInterfaceAddressTest.SunnyDaySourceForDestination/1
[13672:19284243583:ERROR:socket_connect.cc(52)] SbSocketConnect: connect failed: 101
../../starboard/nplb/socket_get_interface_address_test.cc:128: Failure
Value of: source.type == GetAddressType()
  Actual: false
Expected: true
../../starboard/nplb/socket_get_interface_address_test.cc:132: Failure
Value of: GetAddressType()
  Actual: 1
Expected: netmask.type
Which is: 4278124286
../../starboard/nplb/socket_get_interface_address_test.cc:134: Failure
Expected: (0) != (SbMemoryCompare(source.address, invalid_address.address, (sizeof(source.address) / sizeof(source.address[0])))), actual: 0 vs 0
../../starboard/nplb/socket_get_interface_address_test.cc:136: Failure
Expected: (0) != (SbMemoryCompare(netmask.address, invalid_address.address, (sizeof(netmask.address) / sizeof(netmask.address[0])))), actual: 0 vs 0

3>SbSocketAddressTypes/SbSocketGetInterfaceAddressTest.SunnyDaySourceNotLoopback/1
../../starboard/nplb/socket_get_interface_address_test.cc:165: Failure
Value of: SbSocketGetInterfaceAddress(&destination, &source, NULL)
  Actual: false
Expected: true
../../starboard/nplb/socket_get_interface_address_test.cc:166: Failure
Value of: GetAddressType()
  Actual: 1
Expected: source.type
Which is: 4278124286
../../starboard/nplb/socket_get_interface_address_test.cc:167: Failure
Value of: SbSocketGetInterfaceAddress(&destination, &source, &netmask)
  Actual: false
Expected: true
../../starboard/nplb/socket_get_interface_address_test.cc:172: Failure
Expected: (0) != (SbMemoryCompare(netmask.address, invalid_address.address, (sizeof(netmask.address) / sizeof(netmask.address[0])))), actual: 0 vs 0
../../starboard/nplb/socket_get_interface_address_test.cc:174: Failure
Expected: (0) != (SbMemoryCompare(source.address, invalid_address.address, (sizeof(source.address) / sizeof(source.address[0])))), actual: 0 vs 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a number of `SbSocket` implementations in your Starboard port are broken and NPLB rightfully points it out.

For example, in order to pass `SbSocketGetInterfaceAddressTest.SunnyDayDestination` you need to follow the comment from [`SbSocketGetInterfaceAddress` declaration](https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/release_11/src/starboard/socket.h#245):

```
// If the destination address is 0.0.0.0, and its |type| is
// |kSbSocketAddressTypeIpv4|, then any IPv4 local interface that is up and not
// a loopback interface is a valid return value.
```

and

```
// Returns whether it was possible to determine the source address and the
// netmask (if non-NULL value is passed) to be used to connect to the
// destination.  This function could fail if the destination is not reachable,
// if it an invalid address, etc.
```

In other words, the test expects `out_source_address` to be an IP address of the machine and return value to be `true`.

Since you are seeing the same error on linux_x86-x11 build, I suggest you to verify that POSIX function `connect` (used by `SbSocketConnect` implementation on Linux) works well with 0.0.0.0 IP address on your platform.